Next UI NavBarMenuToggle won't show but is working when clicked
For some reason, my navbar menu toggle button (the hamburger) isn't visible. When I hit the breakpoint I set, the button itself works and spawns a menu when clicked, but the toggle button itself is not visible.
export default function NewNavBar() {

    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
    ....
    const makeOfferURL = user ? "/address-validate" : "/intro";

    const menuItems = [
        {text:"Make An Offer", href:makeOfferURL},
        {text:"About Us", href:"/about"},
        {text:"FAQs", href:"/faqs"},
    ];

    return (
        <Navbar isBordered onMenuOpenChange={setIsMenuOpen} maxWidth="full">

            <NavbarContent className="gap-10">
                <NavbarMenuToggle
                    aria-label={isMenuOpen ? "Close menu" : "Open menu"}
                    className="sm:hidden"
                    />

                <NavbarBrand className="max-w-10">
                    <Link href="/">
                        <SmallLogo />
                    </Link>
                </NavbarBrand>

                <NavbarItem className="sm:block hidden">
                    <Link color="foreground" href={makeOfferURL}>
                        Link Two
                    </Link>
                </NavbarItem>
            </NavbarContent>


            <NavbarContent justify="end">
                <NavbarItem>
                    Signup 
                </NavbarItem>
            </NavbarContent>

            {/**Menu Dropdown */}
            <NavbarMenu>
                {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <NavbarMenuItem key={`${item.href}-${index}`}>
                        <Link
                            className="w-full"
                            href={item.href}
                            size="lg"
                        >
                            {item.text}
                        </Link>
                    </NavbarMenuItem>
                ))}
            </NavbarMenu>
        </Navbar>
    )

}


my config file as well:
const config: Config = withUt({
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}",
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  prefix: "",
  theme: {
    colors: {
      "primary-dark": "#001BCC",
      "primary-medium": "#007FFF",
      "off-white": "#F2F1EB",
      "custom-white": "#fffdf7",
      "dark-gray": "#4F4F4D",
      "success-green": "#5cb85c",
      "completed-blue": "#0077B5",
    },
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        ttnorms: ["TTNormsPro", "sans-serif"],
      },
      screens: {
        "3xl": "1815px",
        xs: "425px",
      },
      // Accordion keyframes and animation are used in ShadCN components
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate"), nextui()],
}) satisfies Config;

export default config;

I've tried changing the style and hard-coding it a color, but it just makes the whole div that color and doesn't show the actual button.

What do you see when you go into your browser devtools inspect facility - exactly what CSS is being applied to the hamburger and from where?

@AHaworth Hey! It looks like it was looking for a style named 'currentColor' which i didn't have in my config file, so that solved that.
i Do have a follow up question. Any component I import from nextUI is getting it's style overwritten by the current style i have in my app. How do i make it so these components keep their default styling?
